# How to avoid quotes around string values while creating JSONObject

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am trying to create JSON query string for MongoDB, In order to support regular expression I need to create JSON string that has values without quotes. How do accomplish this in java,

Here is the example of what I am trying to do,

```
  JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
  String title = "gro";
  obj.put("title", "/.*" + title + ".*/");
```

Result is

```
   {"title ":"/.*gro.*/"}
```

Above is no longer treated as a regular expression by MongoDB. What i wanted is,

```
   {"title ":/.*gro.*/}
```

So that MongoDB treats it as a regular expression. Is there any way to accomplish this in java?

Comment: `{"title ":/.*gro.*/}` is not valid JSON, so I doubt you'll find any JSON parser/marshaller that will generate that.

Comment: This would result in invalid JSON. What library are you using and what do you want to accomplish? [For what do you need the regular expression?]

Answer (score 1):

The `/` delimited regular expression syntax is a JavaScript construct.  In [Java](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#regular-expressions) you have to use `java.util.regex.Pattern` like this:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("title", Pattern.compile(".*gro.*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
  String title = "gro";
  String startExpr = "/.*";
  String endExpr = ".*/";

  obj.put("title", startExpr  + title + endExpr );
```